# Find parent sibling td hidden value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find parent sibling td hidden value when clicking correctAttempt class in div.

```
 <tr th:each="m : ${markWiseResultModel}">
      <td th:text="${m.id}" align="center"></td>
      <td class="topicTD">
           <input type="hidden" class="topicId" th:value="${m.topic.id}"/>
           <div th:text="${m.topic.name}" align="center"></div>
      </td>        
      <td data-toggle="modal" style="background:#b8d1f3;">
           <div class="correctAttempt" th:text="${m.correctAttemptCount}" align="center" ></div>
      </td>
      <td th:text="${m.correctAttemptPercent}" align="center" style="background:#99FF99;"></td>        
      <td th:text="${m.wrongAttemptCount}" align="center" style="background:#b8d1f3;"></td>
      <td th:text="${m.wrongAttemptPercent}" align="center" style="background:#99FF99;"></td>        
      <td th:text="${m.correctTotalCount}" align="center" style="background:#b8d1f3;"></td>
      <td th:text="${m.correctTotalPercent}" align="center" style="background:#99FF99;"></td>        
      <td th:text="${m.wrongTotalCount}" align="center" style="background:#b8d1f3;"></td>
      <td th:text="${m.wrongTotalPercent}" align="center" style="background:#99FF99;"></td>        
 </tr>
```

```js
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.correctAttempt').click(function(){
                var id = $(this).parents('td').siblings('.topicTD').find(".topicId").val();
                alert(id);
                $('#correctOutOfAttempt').modal('show');
            });
      });
 </script>
```

Already tried script with no success.

Comment: Show the rendered html.. It seems confusing.. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/f4msdtgf/)</kbd>

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.correctAttempt').click(function(){
        var id=  $(this).parent().prev('.topicTD').find(".topicId").val();
        alert(id);
        $('#correctOutOfAttempt').modal('show');
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.correctAttempt').click(function(){
        var id=  $(this).parent().prev('.topicTD').find(".topicId").val();
        alert(id);
        $('#correctOutOfAttempt').modal('show');
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `closest` to get the parent `tr` element, then you need to find the `.topicId`. Try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.correctAttempt').click(function(){
            var id =  $(this).closest('tr').find(".topicId").val();
            alert(id);
            $('#correctOutOfAttempt').modal('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The advantage of using `closest` instead of traversing rigidly by parent is that you can change your `tr` and `td` structure without having to amend the JS code, so long as the classnames remain the same.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk5s21e2/)